# Sanitizing when storing serialized array

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, sanitization

If I am storing a serialized array to a mysql database should I sanitize before or after using the serialize function. Or do I even need to sanitize at all?

For example:

```
$details['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$details['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$details['phone'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);

$serializedDetails = serialize($details);

// Do SQL query
```

Or

```
$details['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$details['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$details['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];

$serializedDetails = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($details));
```

Or perhaps on the second I can simply do:

```
$serializedDetails = serialize($details);
```

Comment: Why are you serializing an array?  `BLOBS` and `TEXT` are inefficient storage in MySQL.  Can you instead have a row with an `ID`, `NAME`, `EMAIL`, and `PHONE` columns?  You can have `VARCHAR`s for the three data columns.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez The data is actually more complicated than that and possibly different for every query but they all need to go into the same table. But I suppose I could do a little reorganizing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Always* use `mysql_real_escape_string` when dealing with strings that might have quotation marks / slashes. If you don't, you'll get broken / malicious queries. The output of `serialize()` sometimes has quotation marks / slashes, so you should use it. There's no need to serialize the each item of the array beforehand though.

```
$details['name']  = $_POST['name'];
$details['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$details['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];

$serializedDetails = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($details));
```

Just as an example: serializing "hello" will give you: `s:5:"hello"`.

```
$data  = 's:5:"hello"';
$query = 'INSERT INTO tbl (data) VALUES ("' . $data . '")';

// leads to a syntax error from mysql
// (plus it's a huge security hole)
mysql_query($query);
```