# Using C# to duplicated PHP serialized data in MySQL

Tags: c#, php, mysql, serialization

I'm trying to use C# to duplicate the PHP serialize functionality, so I can save data correctly in a MySQL database.

The data I save look exactly like the PHP serialized data, except for some unknown characters.

For example, the data saved by PHP looks like this "a:5:{s:12:"﻿post_name"..." in SQLyog.

But when I copy it to a text editor, it looks like a:5:{s:12:"?﻿post_name"...".

Anyone have any idea what the "?" character is?

Thanks!

Comment: What method are you using to serialize in C#?

Comment: BinaryFormatter, but the ? is set by PHP (I just can't identify what the ? means, so I can duplicate it in C#)

Comment: That question mark might be PHP trying to serialize a null character / value. I would also look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238463/sanitizing-when-storing-serialized-array

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and see if I can duplicate mysql_real_escape_string()